# Run/Debug options are not available on the project's root folder context menu in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, jetbrains-ide

so i first create a project (pytest tests) on my PC. for any of the items in the project's folder, i.e root folder/subfolder/specific module i can start a run or debug session by simply right-clicking on that item in Project Window and selecting 'Run/Debug 'Python tests in ...'. The configurations created match the "Python tests -> Autodetect" template.

then i upload the project to git, clone it to a new folder, and looking at the same context menus i see this:

1. run/debug context menu option is no longer available on the project's root folder;
2. the run/debug context menu options for subfolders/specific modules have changed to 'Run/Debug 'pytest in ...';
3. the configurations created match the "Python tests -> pytest" template.

so my questions:
what is the difference between PyCharm offering me 'Run/Debug 'Python tests in ...' and 'Run/Debug 'pytest in ...' on project's items, where's the Settings toggle for that? how can i make the cloned copy behave the same in IDE, as the original, including the presence of run/debug options on project's root in context menu?

[image: before git]

[image: after git, root]

[image: after git, below root]

**Edit**:

i've figured out how to toggle between 'Run/Debug 'Python tests in ...' and 'Run/Debug 'pytest in ...' in context menus for unconfigured items - it's the 'Default test runner' option in Settings (Autodetect <-> pytest).

but that still does not restore the menu on the root folder.. i can onle enforce it on the root by Marking Directory as Test Sources Root (colored green), but i'm not sure if thats the proper way of doing it, in the original project i didnt have to explicitly mark it that way for context menu to be available.

Comment: what is your main tests folder name ?

Comment: @ozs the original folder name is "test_something". this uploads to git project, named by admin, as just "something". so it gets cloned to somebody else's IDE also as "something". is that the reason PyCharm removes those context menu options on their root?

Comment: yes, because your new test folder has no "test" in its name so pycharm doesn't recognize it automatically.